# Help on this integral

Tags: integration

I'd like to know why this holds

If one have $f(x_t,t)=x_t\mathrm{e}^{\theta t}$

$\int_0^tdf(x_t,t)=x_t\mathrm{e}^{\theta t}-x_0$

That shouldn't be only $x_t\mathrm{e}^{\theta t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is definite integral, $\int_0^t df(x_s,s) = f(x_s,s)|_0^t = x_t e^{\theta t} - x_0 e^{\theta 0} = x_t e^{\theta t} - x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^tdf(x_t,t)= [ x_t\mathrm{e}^{\theta t}]_0^t = x_t\mathrm{e}^{\theta t} - x_0\mathrm{e}^{\theta \cdot 0} = x_t\mathrm{e}^{\theta t} - x_0
$$